# LDAP DirectoryEntry unable to connect via hostname but only via IP address

Tags: c#, asp.net, tcp, active-directory, ldap

When I'm trying to connect to an AD in my computer network by writing the following line:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://hostname.local");
```

I get the following error:

> Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

But when I'm trying to connect to the same computer using its IP I'm able to reach the computer without an error, that is the following line does work:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://The IP of hostname.local");
```

How is it possible that when I'm trying to use the ldap query with hostname I'm getting Logon failure but when I'm using the host name ip address I reach the computer successfully and able to view its AD contents.

Comment: A stupid question first. When you ping "hostname.local", do you get the same IP in "The IP of hostname.local" above?

Comment: Yes. That's how I found the IP in the first place.

Comment: 2nd question is, is "hostname.local" really a hostname or domain name? If it is a domain name then may be there is a problem in the DNS (those SRV records) so that it fails to resolve the DC from domain name.

Comment: It is a domain controller so yes It is a domain name and not a hostname. Can you please elaborate a little bit about these SRV records and explain why sometimes it success to resolve the DC from the domain name and sometimes it fails?

Comment: In Windows 2k+ the domain locator follows this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961830.aspx If no records is found, then it uses the NT4 Locator Service: http://activedirectoryfaq.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-domain-controllers-are-located-in.html    -jim

Comment: Thank you very much!. I'll read it. The reason why I asked @baldpate to elaborate on this subject is to be able to accept his answer (I can't accept a comment) . For now, I'll read the article suggested and if it is possible can one of you please also write an answer so I'll able to accept it?