# Domain controller doesn't initialize LDAPS request

Tags: c#, dns, active-directory, ldap, wireshark

I'm using C# in order to get domains from external domain controller in my forest which contains AD (which is accessable from my computer) :

```
DirectoryEntry deTrustedForest = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}/RootDSE", TrustedForestDnsName));
```

Although I have a **RootCA** in this domain controller I'm keep getting the following exception :

**server is not operational**

Also I can see in wireshark that no **TLSv1** connection is being created (no **ClientHello** and etc..). It seems like the domain controller refuses the request:
[image]

*Note - if I change my computer DNS to the domain controller DNS I'm able to use LDAPS in order get AD.

Can someone give me an idea where the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

From the "*Note-xxx" in your post, does it mean the current DNS cannot resolve the domain name (TrustedForestDnsName)?

Try ping the TrustedForestDnsName in command prompt.
If it can't resolve the IP from domain name, then of course it cannot connect to DC.

Comment: I already tried to ping the TrustedForestDnsName and it works. Any other idea?

Comment: I found another post from you. Is this similar issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645317/ldap-directoryentry-unable-to-connect-via-hostname-but-only-via-ip-address?noredirect=1#comment43727817_27645317

Comment: No. After adding an "A" forward host to the DNS server the hostname has been resolved.